# Visio 2013 Hotkey for View > Page Width?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

Does a Microsoft Visio 2013 hotkey exist, for functionality View > Page Width? Note: keyboard shortcut ALT, W, I exists

For example, hotkey CTRL + SHIFT + W, for View > Fit to Window.

Comment: Downvoters not leaving comments: please clarify how to improve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [Keyboard shortcuts for Visio](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Visio-EE952F31-7E3E-4564-8116-F3ECBB733CC1), No, there is no direct keyboard shortcut for that.

Either keep using the Keyboard chord you are using (ALT, W, I), or perhaps use a program such as [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to create your own shortcut that performs the chording for you.

Comment: Yeah, the most used key when viewing Visio files doesn't have a shortcut key. Thank you micro$oft